# IE6 accessing MVC3 web app loses session state

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-6, session-state

I’m investigating a bug in my MVC3/.NET 4 site which runs on IIS7.5 with integrated pipeline that only manifests itself when accessed using IE6.

The process in pseudo is:

1. Browser requests Page A; server sets
   a Session[] value and responds with
   the page.
2. Enter data onto Page A and
   http post the form back.
3. Server tries to get value out of Session[]
   previously set in (1) but returns
   null >> but only in IE6, 8(.

In IE7, IE8, IE9, Firefox 3.6, Safari 5.0.3, Chrome 10 the same code works without change.

In my global.asax code I put a Session_Start handler in and noticed some strange behaviour.
In IE6 this handler is fired upon every request made **BUT** the Session.SessionID value remains the same. All the other browsers mentioned above only have this handler fire the first time they make a request. So for IE6 even though the session ID is the same each time it is called it would seem that the fact that it is “start”ing a new session seems to have the effect of clearing the data for the Session ID and starting it again hence the null value.

One theory I had was that because some items on the page (images etc…) would be accessed with HTTP whilst the page itself is HTTPS could be why IE6 is causing this behaviour (new session per protocol perhaps?) but I turned off the code that forced HTTPS to be used on the page in question, so all requests would be HTTP. Unfortunately the same behaviour is still observed on IE6.

After a lot of Googling I found things that said stuff like underscores in the domain can cause this (no underscores present in mine), ensure IE6 is accepting cookies (my test VM was set like to accept all session cookies).

Finally in a last ditch attempt:

- I turned every privacy and security setting I could find in IE6 to as low as it would let me
- I added my test site (http://<my machine name>/MyApp) to the list of trusted sites
- Clear temporary internet files and cookies

Still I get the same issue. I have thought of a way to fix it that involves not using Session for this case but I would rather not make changes due to IE6 when it works in all of the other browsers including decendant versions of IE.

**Edit:** Some further testing on another page and when accessed via IE6 the session value is correctly retrieved after being stored by access to another page. More specically:

Working Page - Search:

1. Do a search, results are display and
   criteria are stored in session.
2. Click on one of the results to view it, details page gets criteria in order to build querystring for breadcrumb trail link.

Failing Page - 2 stage login:

1. Go to 1st stage login page, enter username and password, assuming correct store encrypted http only cookie value with username in.
2. Redirect to 2nd stage login page, store 3 index values (List<int>) into a "secret" word in Session
3. Enter 3 characters from a secret word and post back.
4. Access session to get 3 index values - get nothing.

The reason for the failure is evident due to the observations made in the more generic description above. This is just getting weirder by the minute (and more frustrating).